# How to read a csv file from azure blob storage using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded a csv file in to azure blob storage. Now I want to retrieve the file from azure blob storage, I have used the following code. After receiving the csv file I will convert in to json and do some manipulation.

```
var blob = require('../../service/blobstorage');
var chkFile = async function (req,res) { 
    let reqq = {
                           storageName:"consent",
                           blobFileName: "filename",
                           downloadFileName:"filenamee"
                }    
    let storeBlb = await blob.getBlobDataToStreamm(reqq,res)
}
```

In blobstorage file,

```
const getBlobDataToStreamm= async function(req, res){
try{
    var fs = require('fs');
    const storageName= req.storageName;
    const blobFileName= req.blobFileName;
    const downloadFileName= req.downloadFileName;
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + downloadFileName);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With,content-type");
    blobService.getBlobToStream(storageName, blobFileName , res, function(error, result, response) {
        if(error){
            console.log('error',error);
            res.send({error:error, status: false});
        }
        else{
            console.log('resp',result);
            res.end();
        }
    })

  }catch(err){ 
    console.log("err ",err);
    res.send({error:err, status: false});
  }
}
```

chkFile();

But I'm getting the error

> err  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setHeader' of undefined

Comment: `res` is undefined. How are you calling `chkFile`?

Comment: @JamesZ I'm calling chkFile without any param chkFile();

Comment: @JamesZ But where can I add this. Please suggest

Comment: It's @Cerbrus who wrote the comment, not me

Comment: `chkFile` expects 2 parameters, `(req,res)`. You're not using `req`, so you can remove that one, but you need to pass `res`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Even if I pass, Im getting error like res.setHeader is not a function...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code where you're calling `chkFile` method.

Comment: @GauravMantri Updated the code, pls check

Comment: I am guessing that this code of yours is running server-side (may be using Express). Only then you will be able to use `response`. If you're running it on the client side (may be in a console), then the concept of request/response will not apply.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm running this code only in server side manually. Pls help

Comment: Like I said, you will actually need to send an HTTP request (through a browser or Fiddler). Simply calling your JS file like `node index.js` will not work.

Comment: @GauravMantri Is there a different way to get the csv file from blob ?

Comment: What version of Node Storage SDK you're using?

Comment: @GauravMantri 8.17.0

Comment: You can get rid of all the req/res related things and simply use `getBlobToStream` if you're running your code from console.