# Azure function ( blob trigger ) read CSV file with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, csv, azure-functions

What is the best way with Nodejs to read the myBlob buffer parameter in a azure function and write it into a table storage because I'm trying with a file with size of 16MB and it's too slow.

Another thing is when I use context.log() to see the content of the file,  it doesn't show all the content of the file but only part of this.

```
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {

     let data = myBlob.toString("utf8");

     context.log("context", data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBlobToStream or getBlobToText in nodejs to get the blob data.
below is the function.json which is needed for reading the blob:

```js
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "Blob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "folderpath",
      "connection": "CONN_STR"
    }
  ]
}
```

In relate with the code you've provided I add few changes respect to it as below:

```
var blobName = 'BlobName';
blobService.getBlobToText(
    containerName,
    blobName,
    function(err, blobContent, blob) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Couldn't download blob %s", blobName);
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Sucessfully downloaded blob %s", blobName);
            console.log(blobContent);
        }
    });

Converting to the stream as below:
```

```
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
    context.log(context.bindings.myBlob.toString());
    context.log("Blob:", context.bindingData.blobTrigger, "\n Blob Size:", myBlob.length, "Bytes");
};
```

Also check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314772/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-azure-blob-storage-using-nodejs) for more insights.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work

Comment: @cesarandavisa May I know the error you are getting?